# JBehave - best way to reuse/refer already existed story

Tags: bdd, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Each story in my BDD tests starts with the same bunch of steps. 
Is there any way to refer this steps or maybe somehow to "refer" repeatable story.
What is the best way to extract this common part?
Currently, I am using `@Composite` annotation provided by JBehave.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to use a Background scenario.

What this does is to execute the steps from the Background for each scenario.
A disadvantage would be that if the Background fails then all the scenarios from that feature will be skipped and the feature will be marked as failed.

I guess is assuming that if the steps are common and they fail once then they fail every time.
You can see an example in JBehave [documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/story-syntax.html).

Comment: As I understand correctly you propose to have all repeated steps in Lifecycle -> Before section ?

Comment: You write the steps once using Background and they are executed for each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GivenStories** by setting all your steps in a story and call it in other stories like:

```
GivenStories: path/to/precondition2.story,
          ...
          path/to/preconditionN.story

Given ... // normal scenario steps
```

You can also send parameters to those steps:

```
Scenario:  A scenario in which the user can run other stories as pre-requisites
       parametrized using the rows of the Examples table

GivenStories: path/to/precondition.story#{0},
          path/to/precondition.story#{1}

Given ... // normal scenario steps

Examples:
|One|Two|
|uno|due|
|un|deux|
```

reference: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/given-stories.html